# Regex to exclude everything except directories AND string matched files

Tags: java, regex

Good evening, I am working on a package for an existing project.

Because of this there are a large amount of files throughout all directories.

In the netbeans IDE (8.2) there is an excluded files option which accepts a regex.

here is what i found at regextester.com

```
^((?!package).)*$
```

This worked to a fashion, except it hides directories, as a result there is actually only one single file that comes up which is in the root directory of the project, nothing else comes up because they are in sub directories, this was not the desired result.

This is what my current patterns look like in Netbeans where everything matched is excluded from the project file list, i need to add another regex.

Im not sure if the ^ and $ are required but all of the regex have them separated by a pipe.

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(git|hg|svn|cache|DS_Store)$|^Thumbs.db$|^(vq2\-systemz.*)$
```

To make things clearer, What i'm trying to achieve with a regex is to **keep all directories and remove all *files* that match do not match the pattern**.

In case of the exclusion list of netbeans, **everything that matches one of the regex is removed from the file list**. In the regex I believe it needs to be !match package, !match directory, match all other files.

Could anybody please help with this?

PS: Thank you to those who have tried already, i believe i may have confused the question somewhat making answering difficult.

Comment: `^(?!.*/pattern[^/]*$).*` - is it what you want?

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew is the ? at the end a part of the regex?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: okay thank you for your comment, it did not work, all directories and files vanished, even the one file that stayed in my questions regex

Comment: Nobody is a mind reader, just make a list of what you want to match and a list of things that should not match .. jeeez

Comment: Im not looking for a direct exclude this and keep that, there thousands of files and I only want to see the files with the string **parcel2go** as well as the entire directory structure. I hope this makes things clearer. PS: i was mid edit when your comment came through, but thank you i appreciate your effort to improve my question.

Comment: While there may be an answer to this, Ive gone the other route and symlinked the appropriate files instead (Ubuntu). I won't close this because it may yet yield a good or even better solution to that which I have used.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I think I understand now that I know your filter *removes* matches.

**`^((?!package[^/]).)*$`** should work if your regex parser supports negative lookaheads.

This says that it cannot have the string "package" with a "/" after it.

```
/some/path/to/package/package.php (no match)
/another/package/package_name.php (no match)
/another/package (no match)
package.php (no match)
/another/package/file.php (matches)
/another/path/file.php (matches)
```

Comment: I think my question might be hindering us here, I want to keep the structure and the specific package files, so any other files no matter what they are I dont want to see. As this is an exclude list, it excludes everything that matches, so this answer excluded my package files. When i add the ! before package, it excluded nothing. its closer to what i need but not yet there. Im updating my question with the current exclude files entries.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: No, I am afraid that excludes everything too. I have done a work around now, by using a separate project folder with symlinks to my package files within the master. I would still like to be able to do it this way but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Maybe try escaping the / like: `[^\/]` If that still doesn't work, my guess is that the netbeans filter doesn't support negative lookaheads, or there's something about the regex that isn't being parsed correctly.